# NestJS in conjunction with Axios

Tags: axios, nestjs

I have a NestJS application that acts as a BFF (Backend for Frontend) which exposes a certain endpoint. That endpoint uses Axios to send multiple requests to my backend. Some of these requests to the backend can return different status codes, which I want to propagate back to the caller. However, I don't want to catch every request manually. Currently, it throws 500 if any Axios request fails in the pipeline.

I thought about implementing a global exception filter for Axios exceptions, that will check the returned status code from Axios and throw an appropriate `HttpException` exception that NestJS will catch (e.g. if any Axios request failed and returned 401, throw an `UnauthorizedException` which NestJS will catch and return back to the client, instead of 500).

Is it a possible approach, or is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 2):

If you want, you can use [Exception filters](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters)

So first you need to create a file for the exception filter.

```js
// axios.exception-filter.ts
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { AxiosError } from 'axios';

@Catch(AxiosError)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: AxiosError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();

    console.log(exception);

    response.status(400).json({
      statusCode: 400,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
    });
  }
}
```

And in your `main.ts` add this

```js
app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
```

And now in `response.status(400).json({})` you can add everything you want in your body. Like the error message of Axios.

Comment: Thank you, however when I use the `AxiosError` inside the `@Catch` I get: `'AxiosError' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`.

Answer (score 0):

> *Thank you, however when I use the AxiosError inside the @Catch I get: 'AxiosError' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.*

That will happen if you're using a version of `axios` pre 1.0.0, upgrading to 1.0.0 or higher and it will function as expected.

[From the release notes](https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/v1.0.0): Add AxiosError to AxiosStatic [#4654](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/4654)